# Sphinx API search primary key

Tags: php, api, sphinx

I'm trying to select single rows from sphinx by the primary key "id" but sphinx api outputs nothing and sphinx from command line outputs an error. Instead it works when I search any other field.

I have the primary key "id" than other fields like "remote_id" "title" etc...

Example (not working):

```
require("sphinxapi.php");

$cl = new SphinxClient;
$cl->setServer("localhost", 9312);
$cl->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED); // or EXTENDED2
$cl->setLimits(0,10);
$query = "@id 5526";

$result = $cl->query($query);

var_dump($result);
```

Example (working):

```
require("sphinxapi.php");

$cl = new SphinxClient;
$cl->setServer("localhost", 9312);
$cl->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED); // or EXTENDED2
$cl->setLimits(0,10);
$query = "@remote_id 11964";

$result = $cl->query($query);

var_dump($result);
```

How can I fetch a specific record (row) by it's primary key?

Answer (score 0):

Can probably use `setSelect` to alias it to virtual filter, and then `setFilter` on that.

But easier and quicker, can just use `SetIDRange`
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#api-func-setidrange

---

Rather than

```
 $query = "@id 5526";
 $result = $cl->query($query);
```

would be

```
 $cl->setIDRange(5526,5526);
 $result = $cl->query('');
```

Comment: Cool, but I have to retreive the values in reverse order (from the lastest to the 1st) and SetIDRange solution doesn't seem to have any ASCENDING/DESCENDING order option...

Main problem is that my records are continuously growing so I can't arbitrary start from the last one since it would not be the last record anymore after few minutes due to cron updates.

Comment: huh? SetIDRange, just filters the query - 'limit the results to ones withing this range of IDs' - you can use the same to get just one document, matching a specific ID (but I dont know why you would). It does nothing to order the results, but if you do supply a range of ids to retrieve, can order them as normal with setSortMode.